# Unable to Import BACPAC Local Server SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have installed SSMS 18 and SQL Server 2019.

I get this error when trying to import a `.bacpac` file:

[image: 1]

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.DropExternalStreamStatement' from assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and wasted a couple of hours trying to figure it out. I found the eventual answer here: [SQL Server bacpac fails on local import in latest update (Online index operations can only be performed in Enterprise edition of SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65570068/sql-server-bacpac-fails-on-local-import-in-latest-update-online-index-operation)

The problem is SSMS 18.8. Some have said that downgrading to 18.7.1 should work, but I had to go to 18.6 in order for it to work correctly.